# Sitecore Permissions - How to grant access to item for a role, but deny everyone else

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have an item in the content tree that I only want to allow access to a specific role.

i.e

- Anonymous - DENY
- Logged in without my role - DENY
- Logged in with specific role - ALLOW

My initial plan was to add a 'DENY' against the 'Everyone' role, then add a 'ALLOW' against my role.

But as far as I can see this does not work because the 'DENY' of 'Everyone' will always trump the 'ALLOW' of my role?

Comment: Have you read this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979521/sitecore-role-security-make-access-overriding-deny - this explains how deny between roles differs with deny for users ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is break inheritance on the item so that any previous permissions that have been provided will be eliminated. Then, give permissions only to the role you want.

This will achieve the "Deny Everyone" you are attempting to do, but know that this means that if you try to apply a 'global' security higher in the tree you will need to repeat it at this level. For example, if you have a Content Admin role that can do anything anywhere, you would have to re-apply the Content Admin role on this item.

Comment: Nice one. Am I the only one who thinks the way this works is a bit weird?

Comment: With users that belong to a single role, it seems odd. But if you consider a multi-role scenario, you need 'Deny' to trump 'Allow'. Otherwise a user with two roles (one denied, one allowed) would be allowed to view content they shouldn't. The current mechanism is a 'conservative' model where it treats the 'Deny' as the priority.

Comment: I think in my mind I was expecting the ability to apply a priority order of roles to manage any conflicts. I think that approach would be more 'obvious' and intuitive than this way of doing it.